# screenshot after manipulating page in Phantom.js

Tags: javascript, phantomjs

I would like to get the screenshot of a web page after I have clicked around a bit, represented by the function `clicking()` however it only renders the original page.  How can I get it to render the page after `page.evaluate()`?

```js
var page = require('webpage').create();

page.onLoadFinished = function(){ 

    page.evaluate( function(){

        clicking();
        return document.getElementById("canvas");

    })

    page.render("screenshot.html");
    phantom.exit();
}

page.open('http://localhost:8000/index.html');
```

Comment: Where is `clicking` defined? It must be defined inside the `evaluate` call.

Answer (score 0):

you can set a console.log in your page to render and then set the phantom to listen for console events, you can check the type and even the text so you can get creative on that